# Date converstion in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In groovy I was using below to generate date in the format `"2020-09-14T06:00:00Z"` in Ready API 3.3.1

```
def today = new Date()
return today.format("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + today.format("HH:mm:ss") +".000Z"
```

After updating to 3.3.2 It's giving me an error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.format()
   is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [yyyy-MM-dd].
```

Could someome help

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Groovy the Date extension methods have been moved to their own library, which you will have to add to your project.  For example, if you are using Gradle as your build tool, you may want something like this:

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-dateutil', version: '3.0.5'
```

If using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-dateutil</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```